# Android - Adding items to an ArrayList then export to CSV

Tags: java, android, csv, arraylist

I am trying to add items to an ArrayList then export the list to a CSV file on the SDCARD, here is a code sample:

```
try 
{

  String csv = "/sdcard/order.csv";
      CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(csv));                                        
  HdwOrderCursor = HDWDBHelper.fetchAllOrders();
  startManagingCursor(HdwOrderCursor);
  List<String[]> mArrayList = new ArrayList<String[]>();
  HdwOrderCursor.moveToFirst();
  while(!HdwOrderCursor.isAfterLast()) {
                      mArrayList.add(HdwOrderCursor.getString(HdwOrderCursor.getColumnIndex(HDWDBHelper.KEY_ITEMNUM))); //add the item                      
                      HdwOrderCursor.moveToNext();                                               
  }

  writer.writeAll(mArrayList);  
  writer.close();        
}
```

The 'mArrayList.add' is having an error "The method add(String[]) in the type List is not applicable for the arguments (String)", not sure what this means.

Comment: It means you're trying to add the wrong data type. You're trying to add a String to an ArrayList that contains String arrays (String[]).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The 'mArrayList.add' is having an error "The method add(String[]) in the type List is not applicable for the arguments (String)", not sure what this means.

This is a pretty clear error, what it tells you is:

1)  That the method "mArrayList.add()" takes a String[] as it's argument.
2)  That you're attempting to pass a String in to the .add() method, not a String[].

So you need to check and make sure that your methods are returning the arguments you expect, and if they are then you need to modify your add code to address this.

Basically what you have done:

```
List<String[]> mArrayList = new ArrayList<String[]>();
```

This call creates a List of String[]s.

In this call:

```
mArrayList.add(HdwOrderCursor.getString(HdwOrderCursor.getColumnIndex(HDWDBHelper.KEY_ITEMNUM))); //add the item
```

You explictely get a STRING from the DB, and then attempt to put a String into your list of String[]'s.

A quick work around for this is to do:

```
 mArrayList.add(new String[] {HdwOrderCursor.getString(HdwOrderCursor.getColumnIndex(HDWDBHelper.KEY_ITEMNUM))}); //add the item
```

However, I don't actually think that you want a list of String[]'s, so the better option would be to change:

```
List<String[]> mArrayList = new ArrayList<String[]>();
```

to:

```
List<String> mArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Comment: When I change to List<String> mArrayList = new ArrayList<String>(); my writer is in error with "The method writeAll(List<String[]>) in the type CSVWriter is not applicable for the arguments (List<String>)".

Comment: Did you write the writer or is it a pre-existing class?  If you wrote it you can modify it to accept Strings, or you can use the mArrayList.add(new String[] {HdwOrderCursor.getString(HdwOrderCursor.getColumnIndex(HDWDBHelper.KEY_ITEMNUM))}) call, which will wrap your string returns in string[]'s.  The question is really one of whether you need arrays of strings or not.

Comment: I can't find the hdrCursor etc.. objects online to do any further research.

Comment: It is a pre-existing class, "openCSV"

Comment: Then use:
mArrayList.add(new String[] {HdwOrderCursor.getString(HdwOrderCursor.getColumnIndex(HDWDBHelper.KEY_ITEMNUM))});

Answer (score 0):

`Cursor#getString` returns a `String`, not a `String[]` array. You either have to make your ArrayList hold `String` objects (`List<String> mArrayList = new ArrayList<String>`) or wrap the result of your cursor in an array:

```
`mArrayList.add(new String[] {HdwOrderCursor.getString(HdwOrderCursor.getColumnIndex(HDWDBHelper.KEY_ITEMNUM))});
```